# How to do ajax on this scenario?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, webmethod

javascript code

```
  function new_person_adder1() {

                var dataAjax = {
                    'entry_new_person_': $('#entry_new_person_1').val(),
                    'pop_new_person_identity_no': $('#pop_new_person_identity_no1').val(),
                    'identity_type_no': $('#select2_identity_type_bc_for_new_person_1').val()
                };
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'WalkReserve.aspx/quick_person_entry',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataAjax),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.d);
                        if (data.d > 0) {
                            alert('Successfully Added');
                        } else {
                            alert('Failed to entry data!');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Failed!');
                        console.log('Failed' + result.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
```

C# code

```
 [WebMethod]
            public static string quick_person_entry(dynamic entry_new_person_, dynamic identity_type_, dynamic pop_new_person_identity_no)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(BAL.pop_quick_person_entry(entry_new_person_, identity_type_, pop_new_person_identity_no));
            }
```

ajaxdata
  [image]

i am getting following error

```
Failed{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 
 \u0027identity_type_\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at 
 System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

I want to send do ajax here but for some weird reason I am not able to do it.
I am getting above error. can anybody point my mistake or help me?

Comment: There's no value for `identity_type_`.  There *is* a value for `identity_type_no`.  It looks like the model binder doesn't think those are the same thing (since they have different names).

Comment: That was the issue?  I'll add it as an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the parameters the method expects:

```
entry_new_person_
identity_type_
pop_new_person_identity_no
```

And the parameters being sent:

```
entry_new_person_
identity_type_no
pop_new_person_identity_no
```

The middle parameter is different.  It's *similar*, but it's not the same thing.  The model binder isn't smart enough (thankfully) to match things which are just *similar*.  Changing the key in the JavaScript code should fix it:

```
var dataAjax = {
    'entry_new_person_': $('#entry_new_person_1').val(),
    'pop_new_person_identity_no': $('#pop_new_person_identity_no1').val(),
    'identity_type_': $('#select2_identity_type_bc_for_new_person_1').val()
};
```

(Or changing the parameter name in the method would fix it too.  Depends on which one is a bigger change.  For example, if you have tons of JavaScript calls to this method then a single change to the method would be easier than many changes to the invocations of the method.)

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing `dataType: 'json'` then It will work.

And define Web Type in web mthod as `POST`